# How to add new entry in firebase in webAPP

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

This is data structure on path https://code.firebaseio.com/products2

[image]

Now i want to add new entry on products/2586/Variants. Say entry is 112: true

I have written this function.

```
$scope.AddProductVariant2 = function(Product, Variant)  {
  //ProductService.AddProductVariant (Product, Variant);

  var key = Product.ProductID;
  var productRef = firebase.database().ref();
  var updates = {};
  var variant = {};
  variant[Variant.VariantID] = true;
  updates['products2/' + key + '/' + 'Variants'] = variant;
  /*
  firebase.database().ref('products2/' + key + '/' + 'Variants').set({
    variant
  });
 */

 return productRef.update(updates);
};
```

But it is erasing all old entries.

How to add new entry without touching old one here?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.update` instead of `.set`. Set removes all previous entries.

So do `ref.update(object)` where object is your javscript object you're trying to insert.